# ¿Por qué el switch ignora todos los datos ingresados menos el último?

Tags: c++

El código de más adelante es para un solucionador de sudokus. Los parámetros me dicen que debo hacerlo con vectores y pedirle al usuario que ingrese los números base para luego solucionarlo.

Ahora bien, en este ingreso de datos el usuario digita la "coordenada" (2A 4D 5H etc) y posteriormente el valor de 1 a 9 que desea ingresar en esa casilla, utilice un `switch` para que eligiera el vector (fila) donde debe ubicar el dato.

Tengo un problema con esto. A la hora de ingresar los datos El `switch` ignora todos los datos ingresados menos el último (en caso de ser más de un dato ingresado). O sea que técnicamente solo recibe 1 dato además ignora todos los `case` hasta que llega al último (al I) y asigna a este vector el único valor que leyó, ignorando si el código es eficiente o no porque aun estoy aprendiendo.

Aquí el código:

*El ultimo chorro de código es porque debo imprimir los datos en la cuadricula del sudoku*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define ESC 27
char tecla;

using namespace std;

  char Fila;
  int Columna, ValorIngresado, opcion;

 int main ()
{ int FilaA[9];
int FilaB[9];
int FilaC[9];
int FilaD[9];
int FilaE[9];
int FilaF[9];
int FilaG[9];
int FilaH[9];
int FilaI[9];

   system("color 06");
   printf("Presione cualquier tecla para iniciar la ejecucion, Esc para salir.");
  tecla=getch();
  if (tecla!=ESC)
  {

   system("cls");
   printf(
"   --------||\t\t    _  _  _  _                             _                     _                     \t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t  _(_)(_)(_)(_)_                          (_)                   (_)                    \t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t (_)          (_) _         _     _  _  _ (_)    _  _  _    (_)     _  _         _ \t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t (_)_  _  _  _   (_)       (_)  _(_)(_)(_)(_) _ (_)(_)(_) _ (_)   _(_)(_)       (_)\t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t   (_)(_)(_)(_)_ (_)       (_) (_)        (_)(_)         (_)(_) _(_)  (_)       (_)\t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t  _           (_)(_)       (_) (_)        (_)(_)         (_)(_)(_)_   (_)       (_)\t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t (_)_  _  _  _(_)(_)_  _  _(_)_(_)_  _  _ (_)(_) _  _  _ (_)(_)  (_)_ (_)_  _  _(_)\t\t||--------   \n"
"   --------||\t\t  (_)(_)(_)(_)    (_)(_)(_) (_) (_)(_)(_)(_)   (_)(_)(_)   (_)    (_)  (_)(_)(_)   \t\t||--------   \n\n\n\t");

   printf("Oprima una tecla para comenzar!\n\n");
   tecla=getch();
   system("cls");
     opcion=1;

   while(opcion==1)
     {
      printf("Digite el numero de la columna seguido de la letra de la fila donde desea ingresar un numero fijo:\n\t");
        scanf("%d%c",&Columna, &Fila);  

          switch(Fila)
             {
               case 'A': 
                 int FilaA [9],a;
                 for (a=0;a<9;a++)
                 {
                  FilaA[a]=0;
                 }
                   printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                     scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                     FilaA[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
                        while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
                 break;

               case 'B': 
                 int FilaB [9],b;
                 for (b=0;b<9;b++)
                 {
                  FilaB[b]=0;
                 }
                   printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                     scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
                   FilaB[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
                 break;

               case 'C':
               int FilaC [9],c;
               for (c=0;c<9;c++)
               {
                FilaC[c]=0;
               }
                  printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                     scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                        while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
                  FilaC[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               case 'D':
               int FilaD [9],d;
               for (d=0;d<9;d++)
               {
                FilaD[d]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaD[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               case 'E':
               int FilaE [9],e;
               for (e=0;e<9;e++)
               {
                FilaE[e]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaE[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               case 'F':
               int FilaF [9],f;
               for (f=0;f<9;f++)
               {
                FilaF[f]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaF[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               case 'G':
               int FilaG [9],g;
               for (g=0;g<9;g++)
               {
                FilaG[g]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaG[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;   

               case 'H':
               int FilaH [9],h;
               for (h=0;h<9;h++)
               {
                FilaH[h]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaH[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               case 'I':
               int FilaI [9],i;
               for (i=0;i<9;i++)
               {
                FilaI[i]=0;
               }
                 printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                   scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                    while(ValorIngresado>9)
                         { 
                         printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
                         scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
                         }
               FilaI[Columna]=ValorIngresado;
               break;

               default: 
                 printf("La coordenada Digitada es incorrecta,Por favor hagalo nuevamente.");
               break;
             }

      printf("Desea ingresar otro valor?");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);
     }  
   printf("El plano del sudoku es:\n\n"
      "\t\t \t    0      1      2  |   3      4      5  |   6      7      8\n"
     "\t\t \t ______ ______ ______|______ ______ ______|______ ______ ______\n"
     "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tA\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n", FilaA[0], FilaA[1], FilaA[2], FilaA[3], FilaA[4],     FilaA[5], FilaA[6], FilaA[7], FilaA[8]);
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tB\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaB[0], FilaB[1], FilaB[2], FilaB[3], FilaB[4], FilaB[5], FilaB[6], FilaB[7], FilaB[8]);
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tC\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaC[0], FilaC[1], FilaC[2], FilaC[3], FilaC[4], FilaC[5], FilaC[6], FilaC[7], FilaC[8] );
     printf("\t\t     ___|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tD\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaD[0], FilaD[1], FilaD[2], FilaD[3], FilaD[4], FilaD[5], FilaD[6], FilaD[7], FilaD[8] );
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tE\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaE[0], FilaE[1], FilaE[2], FilaE[3], FilaE[4], FilaE[5], FilaE[6], FilaE[7], FilaE[8] );
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tF\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaF[0], FilaF[1], FilaF[2], FilaF[3], FilaF[4], FilaF[5], FilaF[6], FilaF[7], FilaF[8]);
     printf("\t\t     ___|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tG\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaG[0], FilaG[1], FilaG[2], FilaG[3], FilaG[4], FilaG[5], FilaG[6], FilaG[7], FilaG[8] );
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
     printf("\t\tH\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaH[0], FilaH[1], FilaH[2], FilaH[3], FilaH[4], FilaH[5], FilaH[6], FilaH[7], FilaH[8] );
     printf("\t\t \t|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n"
 "\t\t \t|      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |      |\n");
 printf("\t\tI\t|  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |  %d   |\n",FilaI[0], FilaI[1], FilaI[2], FilaI[3], FilaI[4], FilaI[5], FilaI[6], FilaI[7], FilaI[8] );
 printf("\t\t     ___|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|\n\n\n");
}

}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el error está en las 237 líneas de código que has publicado? ¿No hay un sitio concreto en que el error pueda estar localizado?

Comment: El ingreso de datos esta en el switch, y tengo un problema grave con el ingreso, pero la verdad no estaria seguro de si esta ahi, puede que el error este en la impresion final

Comment: mas alla de la gran respuesta que recibiste, para tu proxima pregunta te recomendaria esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Reducir el código, para que sea mínimo, y presente el error, es tan buena practica que a veces haciendo esto encuentras el error.

Answer (score 11):

**evita el uso de variables globales**

Y no sirve como excusa que estás aprendiendo... ya que estás en ese estadio es mejor empezar a hacer las cosas bien... además únicamente tienes una función, luego no hay excusa posible.

**si estás en C++ usa C++**

`printf`, `scanf` y demás son reliquias de C. Acostúmbrate a usar las clases propias de C++ `cout` y `cin`.

**En C++ es legal declarar variables dentro de los `for`**

Es preferible esto:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
  // ...

for( int j=0; j<9; j++ )
  // ...
```

A esto:

```
int i;
for( i=0; i<9; i++ )
  // ...

int j;
for( j=0; j<9; j++ )
  // ...
```

¿Por qué? Porque evita errores tontos a la hora de programar. ¿Por qué solo se ejecuta un bucle?:

```
int i;
for( i=0; i<9; i++ )
  std::cout << i;

int j;
for( j=0; i<9; j++ )
  std::cout << j;
```

Con la estructura que yo te digo el error saltaría solo:

```
for( int i=0; i<9; i++ )
  std::cout << i;

for( int j=0; i<9; j++ )
//            ^ error de compilacion, i no esta declarada
  std::cout << j;
```

> El switch ignora todos los datos ingresados menos el último

```
int main ()
{ int FilaA[9]; // <---

// ...

case 'A':
  int FilaA [9],a; // <---
  for (a=0;a<9;a++)
  {
    FilaA[a]=0;  // (1)
  }
  printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
  scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
  FilaA[Columna]=ValorIngresado; // (2)
  while(ValorIngresado>9)
  {
    printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
    scanf("%d", &ValorIngresado);
  }
  break;
```

Fíjate en las dos líneas comentadas... tienes una variable declarada igual. ¿Cual dirías que estás modificando en `(1)` y `(2)`? Exacto, la segunda... una variable con una vida tan efímera como el propio `case`. Dicho de otra forma. Los cambios que haces en `FilaA` se pierden cuando la ejecución abandona el `case`... si hicieses caso de los warnings del compilador verías que te están chivando el problema:

```
..\untitled\main.cpp:57:13: warning: variable 'FilaA' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         int FilaA [9],a;
             ^
..\untitled\main.cpp:73:13: warning: variable 'FilaB' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
         int FilaB [9],b;
             ^

... y sigue
```

Aparte de eso fíjate que en cada `case` estás reescribiendo el array `FilaX` correspondiente:

```
  case 'A':
    int a;
    for (a=0;a<9;a++)
    {
      FilaA[a]=0; // <<---- AQUI!!!
    }
    printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
```

Esto se evita inicializando los arrays según los declaras. Eso y borrar los bucles de cada `case`:

```
int main ()
{
  int FilaA[9] = {0};
  int FilaB[9] = {0};
  int FilaC[9] = {0};
  int FilaD[9] = {0};
  int FilaE[9] = {0};
  int FilaF[9] = {0};
  int FilaG[9] = {0};
  int FilaH[9] = {0};
  int FilaI[9] = {0};

  // ...

  case 'A':
    printf("Digite un valor entre 1-9 que desea ingresar en la posicion [%d%c]: \n\t", Columna, Fila);
```